# Subtract two numbers multiply by another number add this result to a date then convert it to a date

Tags: mysql, sql, date-arithmetic

I am trying to figure out how to subtract two numbers and multiply it by 12 then adding it to a date. This would be the formula:

```
((360-240)*12) + 5/1/2015
```

The result should be `4/10/2019`

I've tried `str_to_date` and variations of simple math, but am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select adddate('2015-05-01', (360-240)*12)
```

Output:

```
2019-04-10
```

See [SQLFiddle live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/1494)

---

FYI, the only place in the world where the whacky *month-day-year* date format is used is the USA. For clarity and portability, consider using the standard date format *year-month-day*.

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks everyone for your answers.

Comment: @benjo if an answer gave you a solution, please accept it. If more than one answer worked for you, accept the one that worked best for you. Accepting answers helps other who follow quickly find a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one, mate:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE('2015-05-01'), INTERVAL ((360-240)*12) DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dateadd function. It should be straight forward.

Comment: Should be `date_add()` -- something like `select date_add('2015-05-01', interval ((360-240)*12) day)`